# having problem with installed php 7.3 on Mac mojavie over php7.1.33 with home-brew and

Tags: macos, homebrew, macos-mojave, php-7.3

I have installed php7.3 on Mac 10.14.6 Mojave.

when I use php-v on germinal I get php 7.3.16

when I run php()info I get php7.1.33

when I run which php  I get /usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin/php

what do I do now

Comment: You can try running `brew doctor` and seeing if homebrew is detecting these issues but needs you to manually run a separate command to overwrite the older version.

Comment: brew doctor dose not return any broken links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not added the 
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.3/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
to 
 httpd.conf